# Phone links are not working inside iframe though it does work in div in iOS9 web. how to make phone links make work in iOS9 safari?

Tags: javascript, web, ios9

Hi I was trying phone links inside iframe in iOS9. Phone application doesn't open up in safari in iOS9. When i tried same link inside then it is working there.

I was trying below anchor tag. This code opens up phone application when put inside div. But same code doesn't work inside iframe. Please suggest how does it make to work inside iframes as well?

Please use below code to see phone link outside iframe

```
<a href = "tel://1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>
```

Please use below code to verify phone link inside iframe.

```
<iframe  id = "test" style = "border:none;"></iframe>
<script>
var iframe = document.getElementById("test");
var iDoc = iframe.contentDocument;
iDoc.write('<a href = "tel://1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Today I had the same problem and found a simple solution for it. Just use target="_parent" and the Links will also work in safari on iOS9.

```
<iframe  id = "test" style = "border:none;"></iframe>
<script>
var iframe = document.getElementById("test");
var iDoc = iframe.contentDocument;
iDoc.write('<a target="_parent" href = "tel://1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This does work. In my case, there are multiple parent iframes, hence I used target = "_top" for anchor tag.

Comment: when I use target="_parent" it works for tel but mailto doesn't work. Any idea how to resolve that ?

Comment: I had a very similar issue and this question solved my problem.  Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65061855/how-do-i-just-get-my-href-tel-on-the-latest-version-of-safari-to-immediately/65062132#65062132